Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: fetch failed
Getting this error while trying to run my tests cases with anchor
Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Connection.getLatestBlockhash (/home/jimii/Documents/crew/stream-nft/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4593:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/home/jimii/Documents/crew/stream-nft/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:147:9)
    at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (/home/jimii/Documents/crew/stream-nft/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
      ✔ Admin initializes the protocol sate (860ms)

Not sure why the RPC call is failing given that airdrop and deploying the program still works on my machine.

This is strange... what versions are you using for web3.js, Anchor, and your test validator? I wonder if it's trying to call the old getRecentBlockhash endpoint

My environment solana-cli 1.17.28 && anchor-cli 0.29.0. In my package.json "@solana/web3.js": "^1.91.7", && "@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.29.0",.
I also raised the error on the anchor repo but was closed because I cannot reproduce it.

on, Linux Pop OS. Fixed the error by changing my DNS to point to the Google DNS server.
Start the resolvconf service if it's not on
sudo systemctl start resolvconf.service
sudo systemctl enable resolvconf.service

Check the status
sudo systemctl status resolvconf.service


Update your DNS configuration resolveconf/head to point to Google's DNS servers.
Open the file
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head

add add
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Update resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf --enable-updates
sudo resolvconf -u

Restart the corresponding services
sudo systemctl restart resolvconf.service
sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved.service

guide: https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/change-dns-server-on-ubuntu/
